# Ethernet connection shows unidentified network with no internet access

Tags: networking, internet, ip, ethernet, dhcp

For years I've used a physical Ethernet connection for my internet access, then a few days ago it went down and said it was an unidentified network with no internet access. I dug out a wifi card and plugged that in and it works (not ideal due to the distance from the router but it connects). The other computers connected via wifi/cable all work as well.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the network card, updated drivers, reset the TCP/IP stack, released and renewed the IP address, enabled DHCP, checked the firewall settings, removed and reinstalled antivirus, manually set the IP and default gateway, still nothing...

When you run the diagnose feature within Windows it returns: "Ethernet 2" doesn't have a valid IP configuration. Not fixed.

Output from ipconfig /all:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Work
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network Connection #
2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b534:b0b3:ad1:1da2%18(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.29.162(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301989888
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-93-FE-F2-00-16-76-AA-A3-75

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-02-72-91-16-16
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8188SU Wireless LAN 802.11n US
B 2.0 Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-02-72-91-16-16
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d1:2c7f:28a0:1ce4%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, August 2, 2014 6:21:12 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, August 3, 2014 7:08:43 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301990514
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-93-FE-F2-00-16-76-AA-A3-75

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0F0A1572-FE9D-4F61-8D41-CB325F939144}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C1FE707E-1751-4EF3-8FEF-7E9988AA0333}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Results from netstat -e (Cable unplugged, wifi off):

```
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                       1358924         1405148
Unicast packets                   3              13
Non-unicast packets           14624           15280
Discards                          0               0
Errors                            0               0
Unknown protocols                 0
```

Results from netstat -e (Cable plugged in, wifi off):

```
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                       1358924         1498552
Unicast packets                   3              13
Non-unicast packets           14624           16224
Discards                          0               0
Errors                            0               0
Unknown protocols                 0
```

Comment: Does the status of the ethernet port still change if you plug a cable in (that is does it know a cable has been plugged in still)? Does the link light come on? Have you tried a different ethernet cable? Have you tried a different port on the router? Do you have another machine to try with your router (to rule it out)? Do you have something else you can connect your machine to (to rule out the machine)?

Comment: Okay sounds good, I'll post back within a week or so once the new card gets here and I can try it out.

Comment: (By the way, for some reason I didn't even notice this: Your MAC address is being picked up as 00-00-00-00-00-00. This is *very* strong additional evidence of an ethernet controller failure. I cannot imagine any software cause for this aside from completely broken drivers, which is unlikely especially given how common the Intel controllers are.)

Comment: @JasonC New card arrived today, works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here could be with MAC address (physical address), here in your screenshots is showing zeros. Try to see if that is changed in properties for your Intel lan card, maybe some values are changed they should be on default-factory value.

Also you can try to manually change MAC address. First three fields in MAC address represent the vendor of the network card, search for it and find some physical address number. You can also look for some free app for network card manipulation.

Comment: A device that works then suddenly stops working and reports 00's for the MAC address is unlikely to be fixable by attempting to change the MAC address in software. This is like forcing a dead guy's eyes open with your fingers in hopes that it will make him alive again.

Comment: Thats ok Jason if you say so , i was just trying to help. :-)   nice comparation you have there

Comment: Here i Google search and found this:   No internet Connection. Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00  http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=209982        if i can send a link, because it is to long to copy and paste.  I use to have this problem some time ago and i fix it with MAC address change.